# Flask-SQLAlchemy how to store queries without running them?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

So I came up with something like this:

```
def someFunction(carPool):
    dict = {
        'redcars': models.RedCar.query.all(),
        'bluecars': models.BlueCar.query.all(),
        'greencars': models.GreenCar.query.all()
    }
    cars = dict[carPool.lower()]
```

But the problem here is that every time this function is called, all 3 queries will be running and their results will be stored in the dictionary.

So I want to ask if there is any way to do something similar to this but without running all the queries or without writing a bunch of if-elses  ?

Comment: Don't call `all()` when forming the dictionary.

Comment: Your solution is pretty simple indeed but does not take into consideration the case when you want to run more queries in 1. For example:
dict = {
    'allcars': models.RedCar.query.all().extend(models.BlueCar.query.all()).extend(models.GreenCar.query.all())
}

Answer (score 0):

While looking on Stack Overflow of ways to reproduce the switch statement I came across a solution that had a dictionary that was using lambda functions as values so I came up with this:

```
def someFunction(carPool):
    dict = {
        'redcars': lambda _: models.RedCar.query.all(),
        'bluecars': lambda _: models.BlueCar.query.all(),
        'greencars': lambda _: models.GreenCar.query.all()
    }
    cars = dict[carPool.lower()]('random var')
```

Maybe it's not the the best solution but it gets the job done so I will leave it here, maybe others will find it useful and save some lines of code.